# manipulating string in R

Tags: string, r, stata

I have a following `stata` code which I am trying to convert to `R`:

`dataframe`

```
    y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6  y11 y12 y13 y14 y15 y16
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   2   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   2   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   8   1   2   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   2   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   2   0   0
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2   2   5   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   2       1

local z1 "y1 y12 y3 y4 y5 y6"
local z2 "y11 y12 y13 y14 y15 y16"
local i = 1
local n : word count `z1'
gen k=.

while `i'<=`n' {

    local z1`i' : word `i' of `z1'
        local z2`i' : word `i' of `z2'
        replace k=max(0,`z1`i'')*(`z2`i''==2|`z2`i''==1)
        local i=`i'+1
    }
```

Expected output:

```
k
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
```

I used the following equivalent `R` code:

```
      dataframe$z1<- "y1 y12 y3 y4 y5 y6"
      dataframe$z2<- "y11 y12 y13 y14 y15 y16"
      i<-  1
      n<-sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", z1), length) + 1
      dataframe$k<-NA

    for (j in i:n){
  .... #I wanted to refer to each word of z1 
  ...#e.g.,dataframe$z1[i]<-which gives word i of z1 
  .. #I wanted to refer to each word of z2
  ... #e.g.,dataframe$z1[i]<-whicg gives word i of z2 

   dataframe$k<-with(dataframe, pmax(0,z1[j])*ifelse(z2[j] %in% c(1,2),1,0))

}
```

The dotted lines indicate that I was not able to find the equivalent code in `R`. I would appreciate if you could help me in this regard.

```
    # Updated Stata codes and data (number of observation is reduced to 10)

y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6  y11 y12 y13 y14 y15 y16
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

y111    y112    y113    y114    y115    y116    y1111   y1112   y1113   y1114   y1115   y1116
1   0   0   0   0   0   81000   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   86000   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   96000   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   84000   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   76000   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

    local z1 "y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6"
    local z2 "y11 y12 y13 y14 y15 y16"
    local z3 "y111 y112 y113 y114 y115 y116"
    local z4 "y1111 y1112 y1113 y1114 y1115 y1116"
    local i = 1
    local n : word count `z1'
    gen k=.
    gen r=0
    gen s=0
    gen t=0
    while `i'<=`n' {

        local z1`i' : word `i' of `z1'
            local z2`i' : word `i' of `z2'
            local z3`i' : word `i' of `z3'
            local z4`i' : word `i' of `z4'


            replace k=max(0,`z4`i'')*(`z1`i''==5|`z1`i''==10|`z2`i''==2|`z2`i''==1|`z3`i''==1)
            replace r=r+k if `i'<=3
            replace s=s+k if `i'>3
            replace t=t+k
            local i=`i'+1
        } 

#Expected output

t       r   s       k
81000   81000   0   0
86000   86000   0   0
96000   96000   0   0
84000   84000   0   0
76000   76000   0   0
0           0   0   0
0           0   0   0
0           0   0   0
0           0   0   0
0           0   0   0
```

Comment: It would be great if you added what exactly you want the script to do for those of us  who know R but not stata.

Comment: @athematical.coffee: I have updated the code as per your request. I look forward to receiving the suggestion.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I mean something like "Take the columns from `z1` and `z2` in pairs, e.g. columns y1 and y11, and then find the maximum value in column z1 if the corresponding value (in that row??) of column z2 is 1 or 2, and 0 otherwise". (I am struggling to understand how your expected output comes about).

Comment: You can get the words with `strstplit`: `strsplit(z1, "\\s")[[1]]` returns `[1] "y1"  "y12" "y3"  "y4"  "y5"  "y6"`, which is an array that can be indexed.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: I think it is maximum value of 0 or value in cell in column z1 corresponding to the row in col z2 with either 1 or 2 , and 0 otherwise".

Comment: It might make things more clear if you were to make the example smaller.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: That is the very small section of the actual data with >30,000 observations. My problem is especially with `local z1`i' : word `i' of `z1'` of `stata`code. I still didn't exactly get your solution regarding this.

Comment: You are using terminology that is foreign to R users. There is no data type in R that is a "word". The data appears "numeric" and R has "numeric vectors". We also have "character vectors" and lists. I'm guessing your efforts at constructing data.frames are flawed and that you really need to be studying the ?"[[" page more carefully. You really should explain in English what you are trying to do. For us, Stata is more "foreign" than English.

Comment: @DWin: I agree with the spirit of your comment, but "For us" no doubt means "For most of us R users".

Comment: In response to the revised code: I assume your main interest remains an R translation, which is beyond me. But as before the more idiosyncratic your Stata code, the less likely that anyone can and will know enough Stata and R to want to translate it. From my earlier answers and comments it follows that you could simplify this code considerably. The `local` manipulations can all be replaced. Also it seems that the definition of `z1` contains a typo, as already suggested, so your expected results may or may not be correct.

Comment: @user1493368 -- I'm confused now. I think the critical first step is to figure out what the code should do. Your Stata code is bit a hard to interpret (see other comments and answers) so I suggest putting in words what you would like to accomplish, then solving that problem directly in Stata or R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick makes a good point that your `max` call doesn't reference the previous `k`, so it collapses to a check of the sixth column. Here's the R-equivalent, assuming you really wanted the row maximum. I stored your data in a txt file first.

```
data_all <- read.table("data.txt", header=T)
data_one <- data_all[,1:6]
data_two <- data_all[,7:12]
my_fun_one <- function(x, y) {
  x * ((y == 1) | (y == 2))
}
data_three <- mapply(FUN = my_fun_one, x=data_one, y=data_two)
my_fun_two <- function(x) {
  max(x, 0)
}
k <- apply(data_three, 1, FUN = my_fun_two)
```

This yields

```
> k
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
```

---

Update -- here's the solution to your updated, full problem. It uses, more or less, the same building blocks. Once you're familiar with the basics of R, I think you will get the most mileage out of `apply`, `lapply`, and `mapply`.

```
data_one <- read.table("data_one.txt", header=T)
data_two <- read.table("data_two.txt", header=T)
z1 <- data_one[, 1:6]
z2 <- data_one[, 7:12]
z3 <- data_two[, 1:6]
z4 <- data_two[, 7:12]
my_fun <- function(w, x, y, z) {
  z * (z > 0) * ((w %in% c(5, 10)) | (x %in% c(1, 2)) | (y == 1))
}
z5 <- mapply(FUN=my_fun, w=z1, x=z2, y=z3, z=z4)
r <- rowSums(z5[, 1:3]) 
s <- rowSums(z5[, 4:6]) 
t <- rowSums(z5)
k <- z5[, ncol(z5)]
data_three <- data.frame(t, r, s, k)
```

This yields:

```
> data_three
       t     r s k
1  81000 81000 0 0
2  86000 86000 0 0
3  96000 96000 0 0
4  84000 84000 0 0
5  76000 76000 0 0
6      0     0 0 0
7      0     0 0 0
8      0     0 0 0
9      0     0 0 0
10     0     0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, this is slightly different from what I got in `Stata`. As per @Nick, we are doing rowwise, so the last output should be `2` not `5`. Can you please re-check that?

Comment: @user1493368 Then why bother checking all columns? Just do `generate k = max(0, y6) * (y16 == 1 | y16 == 2)`? Why loop through all columns if you're only using the last column?

Comment: @ Richard: I assume that you are familiar with the `Stata`. I think the updated `Stata` code needs the loop.

Comment: @user1493368 -- Yes, I know Stata and R, but I'm not sure what is your goal in either language.

Comment: : `Stata` simple code is provided below by @Nick. That's my goal.

Comment: @ Richard : Thanks a lot. Since, I wanted to call the variables by name: I just made a slight modification (not necessary for this problem): `z1<-data_one[,c("y1","y2","y3","y4","y5","y6")]`. I will try to learn those apply functions in details. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The Stata code makes little sense any way. With the data given, the code is looping over the variables `y1`, ..., `y6` and the variables `y11`, ..., `y16`. It sets a new variable `k` to missing initially, but regardless of what is true for previous variables the result will be

```
max(0, y6) * (y16 == 2|y16 == 1)
```

which should be more transparent to R users than most of the code presented. The function `max()` returns the larger of its arguments and operates rowwise.

I doubt that is what is intended, but I will not try to guess what is intended.

Comment: @ Nick: Thanks for explaining the `Stata` code. I agree that the code makes little sense because it is only a part of the original codes.

Comment: @1493368: That's no answer at all to my mind. What's upstream or downstream of this code makes no difference to what it does. The code is self-contained and it ignores everything except the last two variables, `y6` and `y16` in your example. If that's the intended result, it's absurdly round-about, meaning that you do not need a loop at all. On the evidence here my guess remains that the Stata code is incorrect.  Also, if you don't understand what the code is intended to do, how can you evaluate R translations of it?

Comment: Agree, but that's not the intended result. I do really need a loop and I can refer to the original code, if you are interested. You are right! As, I am learning to program both in `Stata` and `R, I may not to be able to fully grasp what is going behind the codes. Anyway, thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: I don't understand your stance here. The key question is whether the Stata code you gave us can possibly be correct. Further, if that code differs from the "original code", whatever that is, we really cannot comment on what you do not show us. As before: If you know you need a loop, the Stata code is wrong. This possibly underlies why, as you indicate, the Stata code and the R code as written by Richard don't agree. I will post as another answer a more modern Stata version of your code.

Comment: I will update the `Stata` code, so that it can closely reflects the original code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shorter version of the original Stata code. It takes as given Stata variables (columns, vectors) `y1`...`y6` and `y11`...`y16`.

```
gen k = .

forval i = 1/6 {
    replace k = max(0, y`i') * (y1`i' == 2|y1`i' == 1)
}
```

The `forval` loop cycles over 1,2,3,4,5,6. There is macro substitution so that first time round the loop the RHS is `max(0, y1) * (y11 == 2|y11 == 1)` and last time round the loop the RHS is `max(0, y6) * (y16 == 2|y16 == 1)`. Hence the result coming out of the loop is inevitably the result of the last calculation.

(Edit) I confirm that none of the `local` statements is needed.

(Second edit) I am also assuming that `y12` in the original `local z1 "y1 y12 y3 y4 y5 y6"` was a typo for `y2`.

Comment: Thanks for the short `Stata` code. I have now updated the `Stata` code to reflect the original code. Please let me know whether I can still avoid the `local` statements in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The Stata code can be simplified, as already signalled, to

```
gen k = .
gen r = 0
gen s = 0
gen t = 0
quietly forval i = 1/6 {
replace k = max(0, y111`i')*(y`i'==5|y`i'==10|y1`i'==2|y1`i'==1|y11`i'==1)
     replace r = r+k if `i'<=3
     replace s = s+k if `i'>3
     replace t = t+k
}
```

The revised code does make clear why overwriting `k` is no problem, as each new result for `k` is always used promptly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is easier to understand than the original code.Your code also helped me to figure out the reason for the use of local statement in the original code.